# How do I find biggest difference between adjacent array elements?

Tags: arrays, c

I have already sorted the array in descending order, now I need to find the biggest difference between adjacent elements.

e.g. Input: `arr[] = {2, 4, 8, 11}` Output: `4`

This is what I've tried:

```c
void dif(int a[], int n) {
    int i, max;
    max = abs(a[i + 1] - a[i]);

    for (i = 0;i < n; i++)
        if (abs(a[i + 1] - a[i] > max)) {
            max = abs(a[i + 1] - a[i]);
        }

    printf("%d\n", max);
}
```

Comment: Use `i+1<n` as loop condition to avoid accessing elements outside the array

Comment: Three style suggestions on your code. Use whitespace. Not spacing around variables and operators doesn't make your code more efficient or faster. It _does_ make it harder to read. Second, use braces consistently. Not using them for your `for` loop is potentially introducing a bunch of errors that can still create code that compiles. Third, if you're writing the same thing repeatedly, you may want to factor it out. E.g. `abs(a[i + 1] - a[i])` could be assigned to a variable: `int diff = abs(a[i + 1] - a[i]);` and then that variable `diff` used in the remaining code.

Comment: `abs (a > b)` has no effect  `a>b` will return non-zero if true, thus `abs(a[i] - a[i + 1]) > max)` should be `asbs ( a[i] - a[i+1])`

Answer (score 2):

The `i` variable is not  initalized in the function.
Then you have an overflow problem in your loop `for(i=0;i<n;i++)`
it suppose to be `for(i = 0;i < n - 1; i++)`.
Lastly, `abs(a[i+1]-a[i]>max)` is not safe, `abs(a[i+1]-a[i]) > max`.

Answer (score 0):

I will only write the corrected version of calculation part here as it is the main part needs to be corrected,

```
  max = abs (a[0] - a[1]);

  for (i = 1; i < (n - 1); i++)
    if (abs ((a[i] - a[i + 1]) > max))
      max = abs (a[i + 1] - a[i]);
```

Good Luck and please comment if it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: but what about `abs (a > b)`? `a>b` will return non-zero if true, which case `abs ()` has no effect. In your and OPs case it is `(a[i] - a[i + 1]) > max)`

Answer (score 0):

@NeWi-l's answer has fixed problem w overflow:

```
void dif(int a[], int n) {
    int i, max;
    max = 0; // note you have sorted array thus minimum diff can be 0

    for (i = 0;i < n - 1; i++) 
        if (a[i + 1] - a[i] > max)
            max = a[i + 1] - a[i];

    printf("%d\n", max);
}
```

First to get this: `abs (true)` is always true. iirc Standard says true value is non-zero and false is 0. So no matter what `a > b` returns, it is not going to change `if (abs(a[i + 1] - a[i] > max))`. Meaning if `a > b` returns `-1` it is equally true as if it returns `1`.

> I have sorted array

Why do you use `abs()` sorted array means that `arr[i+1] >= arr[i]`, thus `arr[i + 1] - arr[i]` will return value greater or equal to `0`.